# SQLite subquery substr argument

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I would like to calculate the `length` argument of`substr` using a subquery but I got an error like:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1)
```

Currently I'm using a dummy SELECT there but it's still failing.

```
SELECT substr(names, 0, SELECT ifnull(15, 0)) AS names from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery must be enclosed in parentheses:

```sql
SELECT substr(names, 0, (SELECT ifnull(15, 0))) AS names FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is incorrect, you cannot use `select ifnull(...` in this way. (subqueries must be surrounded by round brackets i.e:
`(select ifnull(...))` but still it is wrong because `ifnull(15,0)` will always return `15`
,ifnull takes 2 arguments and returns the first that is not null.

Just use `SELECT substr(names, 0, 15) AS names from table`

If you don't want nulls:
`SELECT substr(ifnull(names,'some text when null'), 0, 15) AS names from table`

Comment: What do you mean by "this way"?

Comment: You don't get my question. As I said that this is a dummy query. In the real one theres another SELECT instead of 15. SELECT ifnull(15, 0) always returns 15.